# Bidirectional Italian-English dictionary with more than 400,000 translations

Tags: resources

I am looking for a large Italian-English bidirectional dictionary. Currently, the Oxford Paravia Italian Dictionary (third edition) with 450,000 translations is out of print, and the Collins Italian Dictionary (third edition) only has 230,000 translations. What paper dictionary can I use if I want more than 400,000 translations? I know about the Ragazzini published by Zanichelli, but I am not sure if an English speaker learning Italian can use it profitably (instead of an Italian speaker learning English).

Comment: As an EN>IT translator, I have been using Ragazzini daily and I believe it is perfectly symmetrical in its use. Even the foreword and other initial matter, captions etc. are bilingual. What makes you think that it wouldn't be suitable for an English speaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an English>Italian (and occasionally Italian>English) translator, I have been using Ragazzini daily for years and I believe it is perfectly symmetrical in its use. Even the foreword and other initial matter, the table of contents, the captions of pictorial tables etc. are bilingual.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Ragazzini, but from my experience with other bidirectional dictionaries I can tell you they are always intended to be suitable for both directions.

However, once you've mastered the basics of a language I'd recommend you use an Italian-only dictionary as it will greatly increase your vocabulary and force you to think Italian (instead of making relations to your mother tongue).